# I need to understand the logic of Python for/while statements. Python 3.6

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Below is code I have:

```
student_names = ["Mark", "Katarina", "Jessica"]
for name in student_names:
    print("Student name is {0}".format(name))
```

This code will print:

```
Student name is Mark
Student name is Katarina
Student name is Jessica
```

HOWEVER, if I change the `name` in the for statement to `i` or `x` or `student` such like:

```
student_names = ["Mark", "Katarina", "Jessica"]
for i in student_names:
    print("Student name is {0}".format(name))
```

It prints out:

```
Student name is Jessica
Student name is Jessica
Student name is Jessica
```

I need help understanding how python understands that ‘name’ refers to the names in the list. How does it know this?

Comment: Please include the code that produces the "wrong" output.

Comment: https://repl.it/ disagrees with your assertion that simply changing the arg from "name" to "i" doesn't work the same. Is there some other detail you are leaving out? Also, you have tagged this with unused tags.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not know that 'name' refers to the names in list it would work with I, an x also but you have to change it in both for and print

```
    student_names = ["Mark", "Katarina", "Jessica"]
for i in student_names:
    print("Student name is {0}".format(i))
```

but I think you were changing it only in the for part

Answer (score 0):

"I need help understanding how python understands that ‘name’ refers to the names in the list. How does it know this?"

It's not true. I put your code with "i" and "x" instead of "name", and it printed out the same.

For Python, it doesn't matter what is your variable's name is. And i and x do the same as name.

Answer (score 0):

You would have likely changed `name` to `i` in the for item in iterable statement, but forgotten to change `name` to `i` in the formatted print statement too, and run this new for-loop straight after the first.

Notice the subtle differences between `i` and `name` in each of the following three loops.

In:

```
student_names = ["Mark", "Katarina", "Jessica"]
for name in student_names:
    print("Student name is {0}".format(name))

for i in student_names:
    print("Student name is {0}".format(name))

for i in student_names:
    print("Student name is {0}".format(i))
```

Out:

```
Student name is Mark
Student name is Katarina
Student name is Jessica
Student name is Jessica
Student name is Jessica
Student name is Jessica
Student name is Mark
Student name is Katarina
Student name is Jessica
```

Notice that the middle loop only prints the last name in your list of names. That is because `name` was last assigned to the final item in `student_names`, but it is being used for formatting instead of `i` in the middle loop.

In a Python for-loop, you assign a variable to iterate over items of an iterable object.  Common iterable types include `list`, `str`, `dict` and `tuple`.  Any object with an `__iter__` bound method can be used.

In your example, you are iterating over a `list` that contains three items.  This means that your for-loop will repeat three times, once for each item in your list.  If you would also like to keep track of the index for each item in your list, you can use `enumerate`.

In:

```
for i, name in enumerate(student_names):
    print('Student {0}: {1}'.format(i, name))
```

Out:

```
Student 0: Mark
Student 1: Katarina
Student 2: Jessica
```

Here the first variable `i` is assigned to the index of the item that corresponds to `name`.  Try to avoid adding or removing items from anything you are iterating over, as you may encounter some unexpected results.

In:

```
for i, name in enumerate(student_names):
    student_names.remove(name)
    print("Student {0}: {1}".format(name))
```

Out:

```
Student 0: Mark
Student 1: Jessica
```

There are plenty of long-winded explanations about why this happens, but it is best that you avoid removing or adding items to whatever you may be iterating over.